# VSTS/Azure Devops Build Agent Failed to Connect when configuring

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have created a PAT token, Downloaded the latest build agent, run config.cmd

I then paste in my url 
eg https://dev.azure.com/mycompany/_admin/_AgentPool

I Enter the PAT Token i generated earlier which has FULL access

But then i Get Failed to connect. Try again or CTRL-c to quit??

I can access the URL fine via a browser

Comment: mate, consider accepting this answer

Answer (score 3):

your url should be `https://dev.azure.com/mycompany`.

Reading: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops#server-url-and-authentication

Comment: @4c74356b41 I have the same problem but this fix doesn't work for me. Any ideas? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56080646/azure-agent-listener-configure-hangs